# Lambda Calculus Terms

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

According to what I've read so far a lambda calculus term is described as :

$\langle term \rangle ::==$  $\langle var \rangle |\space (\langle term \rangle\space \langle term \rangle) \space |\space (λ\langle var \rangle.\langle term \rangle) $

So many of the lambda terms are defined $recursively$ and the part I struggle with is this one :

Say a lambda term is a variable $x$ and another lambda term is a variable $y$.

According to the second part of the definition some other lambda terms are :

1. $(xy)$
2. $(xx)$
3. $(x(xy))$

How can one interpret the terms above and what is their meaning when they stand alone?

Could you please provide a simple context/example that they make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the (untyped) $\lambda$-calculus, you can think of everything as a function with one argument. So you can take any term $x$ and apply it to any term $y$, i.e. use $y$ as the input to the function $x$.

So your terms have the intuitive meanings:

1. $x$ applied to $y$.
2. $x$ applied to itself.
3. $x$ applied to the result of applying $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Seems a bit more clear now but what does apply mean in the context of variables? How would one apply a variable to a variable? In terms of functions it makes sense as you apply function/variable $x$ to $y$.What if we take the function away though?

Comment: A variable stands in for a "thing". In the $\lambda$ calculus, all "things" are functions with one argument. You can't "evaluate" $(x y)$ (i.e. simplify it any further), since you "don't know" what function $x$ is (it's a variable). But if you were to substitute a $\lambda$-term for $x$, then you could simplify by $\beta$-reduction.

Comment: It's useful to write things like $(x x)$ because then you can write things like $\lambda x. (x x)$, which is the function which takes a function $x$ as input and applies it to itself.